# Why does this line of Google closure look like it looks?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

Why does this javascript line looks like this? I mean, why there's an extra + near the end?

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></' + 'script>'
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#511

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because if you have `"</script>"` inside of a `<script>` tag, the browser will think you have closed your script tag.  It's a pretty common way to include the text `</script>` inside of a string within `<script>` tags.

Comment: Why wouldn't '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></script>' work?

Comment: Note that this little trick has no benefit at all if you load the script as an external file. So it's "just in case"...

Comment: @Terry: Because the HTML parser needs to find the contents of the `<script>...</script>`. Only after that are the contents passed to the JS engine for further processing. The HTML parser is not aware of JavaScript syntax, so it doesn't know wether or not the end tag is inside a string literal.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Thank you. I'm going to have to think about that a bit, maybe play with it a little. The combination of html and Javascript is indeed interesting. It was all so much simpler back in the days of Fortran, but, hey, onward and upward!

Comment: The other way you see it done is `...<\/script>`, since JavaScript sees `\/` as a slash, but the HTML parser doesn't.